# c# property setter body without declaring a class-level property variable

Tags: c#, properties

Do I need to declare a class-level variable to hold a property, or can I just refer to `self.{propertyname}` in the getter/setter?

In other words, can I do this? (where I haven't defined `mongoFormId` anywhere):

```
public string mongoFormId 
{
    get
    {
        return this.mongoFormId;
    }
    set
    {
        this.mongoFormId = value;
        revalidateTransformation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends, where is that code you wrote going?

Comment: You'll get a stackoverflow with that code :)

Comment: +1 StackOverflowException

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can either use automatic accessors *or* implement your own. If you use automatic accessors, the C# compiler will generate a backing field for you, but if you implement your own you must manually provide a backing field (or handle the value some other way).

```
private string _mongoFormId;

public string mongoFormId 
{
    get { return this._mongoFormId; }
    set 
    {
        this._mongoFormId = value;
        revalidateTransformation();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Since this question was asked, C# 6.0 has been released. However, even with the [new syntax options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx), there is still no way to provide a custom setter body without the need to explicitly declare a backing field.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set a field variable and store the value there, if you're going to use custom getter and setter.

With the code you have right now you will be running into a stack overflow exception. When you assign something to `mongoFormId`, you'll execute the line `this.MongoFormId = value;`. This is an assignment to `mongoFormId`, resulting in executing the line `this.MongoFormId = value;`, and so on. It won't ever stop.

The correct way is a field:

```
    private string _mongoFormId;
    public string mongoFormId {
        get { return this._mongoFormId; }
        set {
            this._mongoFormId = value;
            revalidateTransformation();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a backing variable. Take a closer look:

```
get { return this.mongoFormId; }
```

Is going to call the getter on `mongoFormId`, which will call that code again, and again, and again! Defining a backing variable will avoid the infinite recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Check [MSDN Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> While a property definition generally includes a private data member,
>   this is not required. The get accessor could return a value without
>   accessing a private data member. One example is a property whose get
>   method returns the system time. Properties enable data hiding, the
>   accessor methods hide the implementation of the property.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since you get a recursive call to the property.
If I'm not mistaken, the result will be a `StackOverflowException`.
You must use a variable.

```
    private string mongoFormId;
    public string MongoFormId 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mongoFormId;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mongoFormId = value;
            revalidateTransformation();
        }
    }
```

If you don't have to execute `revalidateTransformation`, you can use the auto-property.
This will create a backingfiled for you behind the scene.

```
public string MongoFormId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the code you wrote, you are creating a recursive endless loop on both the get and set. The `this` keyword refer to the current class, not the property you are in.

So yes, you need to declare a private field. And to avoid confusion, create properties following the [MSDN Naming Guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (Use Pascal case for properties, camel case for private fields). And please do the same for your methods, it should be `RevalidateTransformation` instead of `revalidateTransformation` if you follow the C# convention instead of java's.

```
private string mongoFormId;
public string MongoFormId 
{
    get 
    { 
        return mongoFormId; 
    }
    set 
    {
        mongoFormId = value;
        RevalidateTransformation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it both the ways.

If you want to have a class level member variable then do it this way -

```
public class sampleClass
{
     private string _mongoFormId;

public string mongoFormId {
            get { return _mongoFormId; }
            set {
                _mongoFormId = value;
                revalidateTransformation();
            }
        }
}
```

Or do this simple in class, if no need for revalidateTransformation() execution call there

```
public class sampleClass
{
public string mongoFormId {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: make sure, he wants to call `revalidateTransformation();` in setter. You can get '-' for no attention

Answer (score 0):

```
public string mongoFormId {
    get {
        return this.mongoFormId;
    }
    set {
        this.mongoFormId = value;
        revalidateTransformation();
    }
}
```

this way you have the **Function recursive on all paths**
The only way i see is to use a private data member. As other boys tells.