# Databinding for a custom class

Tags: c#, data-binding, dataset

To avoid confusion I translated my code to be more *english speakers friendly*. the `File` is actually `Ficheiro` which does **NOT** exist. So I'm dealing with my **own** class and not `File` from `System.IO`.
I have a `bindingsource` set from a dataset. Controls like `textbox` and `combobox` works fine if I edit and insert new values. But I have a column that is a `varbinary` (to store small pdf files) so I needed a binding control.
My idea was creating a Class called File and inherited from Control class to use `databinding` because also `TextBox` control uses the same to set `databinding` to `bindingsource`.
Problem here is when I call dialog function (see below) I have a `System.StackOverflowException` on File class, content set.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            f.dialog();
}
```

Class file here:

```
class File : Control
{
    private byte[] _content
    public byte[] Content{
        get{
            return _content;
        }
        set{
            _content=value;
        }
    }
    //public string name; //not used for now
    public string ext;
    public string type;
    public string fileName;
    public File(){

    }
    public byte[] getBytes()
    {
        return Content;
    }
    public void dialog(){
        OpenFileDialog fdg = new OpenFileDialog();
            fdg.Filter = "PDF Files | *.pdf";
            if (fdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (fdg.fileName.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileName = fdg.FileName;
                    ext = ".pdf";
                    type = "pdf";
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                        {
                            content = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                            stream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

The way I bind my control to bindingsource:

```
private void Upload_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f = new File();
    f.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Content", this.fBindingSource, "FileContent", false));
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'pEGPIDataSet_ficheiro_ds.Ficheiro' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.fTableAdapter.Fill(this.myautodatasetfromfile.Ficheiro);\
}
```

EDIT:
Now I have another error.

```
private void fBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Validate();
    this.fBindingSource.EndEdit(); //Exception here says that does not allow nulls on the content file Column.
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.myautodatasetfromfile.Ficheiro);
}
```

I added my control and it has contents set. Why I this Exception?

Answer (score 1):

I'm very confusing about your `content` property.
First of all I would try to use local member:

```
private byte[] _content
public byte[] Content{
    get{
        return _content;
    }
    set{ //StackOverflowEx here
        _content=value;
    }
}
```

Please read here: [property setter body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238649/c-sharp-property-setter-body-without-declaring-a-class-level-property-variable)

Comment: it works thank you. But the bindingsource throws and exception when I try to save that byte array with "save button" on bindingnavigator.